# How to enable Strict TLS 1.2 in C# without modifying the registry

Tags: c#, add-in, tls1.2, ms-project

I'm looking for a solution that will enable strict TLS 1.2 using client code. We have C# Addins (office plugins) that must use strict TLS 1.2.

We cannot modify the registry on these client machines. So I am looking for a code solution that allows us to talk directly to our hosted cloud infrastructure running strict TLS 1.2

I have this article in hand but unfortunately we cannot modify the registry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Has anyone had to tackle this problem?

Comment: I think you can force it by setting [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netcore-3.1) to `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.

Comment: Don't you mean disable Tls11?  So old code would of had SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 and new code just SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: @itsme86 his solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @jdweng Essential that is what we needed to but yours and itsme86 suggestion of SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 worked. Thank you.